# When is plugging an equation back into a previous equation it was derived from "productive?"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I came across the following difference in scalar vs vector algebra, and am trying to understand how to update my equation-pushing approach to accomodate it (please click on the image for higher resolution):

[image: scalar vs vector algebra]

So while I recognize that the matrices not necessarily cancelling in the second case is the cause of the difference, I'm confused as to when exactly this kind of situation arises, and when it's "productive" to go back and plug the result of (1 plugged into 2) back into (1) to get a new expression. In the scalar case this yields the same expression back, but in certain other situations it doesn't...? I just feel like I'm missing some general understanding.

Comment: You didn't need the plugging step in either equations, just multiply both sides by the inverse of a or A from left and you're done. This is the step you should be interested in, I think ?

Comment: Sure, sorry for not clarifying, but in this derivation (which is of the least-norm solution to Ax=b), we don't assume in general that A is invertible (or even square).

Comment: Aaah you're right, but there are a lot of possibilities, I can't answer unless to specify the size of A and $A^{*}$